# MATLAB: Indexing into a matrix with a moving window

Tags: matlab, indexing

I am looking for an effective way in order to index into a matrix using a moving window.

```
% Create logical matrix
startRows = repmat([10,10,30,10,40], 1, 3);

logicalMat = true(100, 5, 3);
logicalMat((1:100)' < startRows) = 0;

% Create source matrix
window = 10;
sourceMat = randi(10, [100, 5, 3]);
sourceMat((1:100)' < startRows-(window-1)) = NaN;

% Compute target matrix: For every cell in targetMat, where logicalMat is true,
% compute the product of multVec and the previous 10 rows.
targetMat = nan(100,5);
multVec = randi(10, [1, 10]);
% For instance, targetMat(10,1) should be the product of multVec and sourceMat(1:10,1).
% targetMat(11,1) = multVec * sourceMat(2:11, 1) and so on...
% targetMat(30,3) = multVec * sourceMat(21:30, 3) and so on...
% I am interested in the technique how to address the "moving window".
```

One possible solution might be using a for-loop. However, I would like to know whether there exists a more elegant solution. Also, if I expand the example into the third dimension, I would need a third for-loop. Is it possible to vectorize this problem?

```
% Possible solution using loop
[nRows, nCols, nPages] = size(sourceMat);
for p = 1 : nPages
    for c = 1 : nCols
        for r = startRows(c) : nRows
            targetMat(r, c, p) = multVec * sourceMat((r - window + 1) : r, c, p);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: How much complex computation is it in the real code? The solution for sum won't necessarily be applicable on your complex computation. Please also show what you have tried

Comment: @SardarUsama In the real code I need to multiply a 1x10 vector with the respective moving window. I am trying to work with for-loop, but I don't think that this is the best way.

Comment: You should create an example that reflects what you're actually dealing with. Please also show what you have tried

Comment: @Andi a for loop might not be the "best" way (although loops are not inherently slow) but it's a much better way than code which doesn't work... If you can get a working example with a simple loop to show expected inputs and outputs then optimisation / improvement is much easier to advise on.

Comment: @SardarUsama I provided a fully working example while using a 3D matrix. I am wondering if it makes sense to vectorize the for-loops? Sorry for editing the original question that often. It wasn't meant to waste your time!

Comment: It seems you are trying to implement a convolution. See `conv` for convolutions along one dimension, or `convn` for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, it's really hard to advise without more specifics, but you could try try the [filter2](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html) or [imfilter](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) functions for this type of thing. With more description of what you are trying to achieve and why, someone may be able to give a more specific answer